# web3 1.0 in production

Tags: dapp-development

I have been using web3 1.0 (v26-beta) in the development of my dApp without errors. The smart contracts are already on Rinkeby and I intend to deploy them in mainnet in a near future.

Are there dApps in production using web3 1.0?

Answer (score 2):

I see variuos professional tutorials online with 1.0 beta. And it contains many functions and features that was not previously supported in previous versions.

I believe that many are using 1.0 beta in production environment.